# SVN: Authentication failing erratically

Tags: svn, version-control

I work at a company with a large SVN server system.  This problem was "solved" by the IT department, but in reality it was chalked up as an SVN anomaly.  Basically, my SVN authentication fails 90% of the time I try to update, commit, etc.  I get this error:

```
Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://REPO_URL' 
Error: OPTIONS of 'http://REPO_URL': authorization failed: Could not 
Error: authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (http://URL)
```

(with REPO_URL being the actual URL, I've tried HTTPS as well)

Now, if I keep attempting to login, after probably 50 retries, the SVN system will seemingly "unlock".  For a brief period of time, I will have the normal ability to commit, update, etc with no problems.  I might come back 30 minutes later only to be "locked out" again.  IT says that there is a password mismatch logged in the system for every time I retry.  I can't seem to figure out what the issue could possibly be.  Obviously my password is correct because it authenticates *sometimes*, but for the life of me I can't figure out why it seems to lock me out periodically.  Any ideas?  Or is black magic really at play here?

Comment: May be some background application try to use old credentials and (after several tries) lock your account?

Comment: IT mentioned that logins on different computers could cause this as well

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:** without the knowledge of Apache's config (SVN-part) and (related) network-infrastructure it would be just guesses and voodoo, but you can at your side

1. If you have SVN-credentials cached locally ($Subversion\auth\svn.simple), you can verify it (in case of Windows-host only - `TSvnPwd` may help) and|or remove related with your repository file
2. You can always (or only once after clearing cached credentials) use svn  commands with (verified as good and correct) `--username` and `--password` options

**Task for your IT:** intercept traffic before repository-server but **after last active node** decode it (plain http is easy task) and verify integrity and permanence of transferred data